# Can't send / receive socket messages?

Tags: java, sockets, networking, serversocket

I am trying to programm a little chat console, because I've recently learned to work with `ServerSocket` and Sockets. But I have a problem, I am not receiving / sending any messages what am I doing wrong?

Class:Chatting (Main)

```
package chatting;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Chatting {

public static Client client;
public static Server server;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Your username: ");
    String name = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.print("connect to: ");
    String ip = sc.nextLine();
    client = new Client(ip.split(":")[0], Integer.parseInt(ip.split(":")[1]), name);
    while (true){
        String chat = sc.nextLine();
        client.send(chat);
    }
}

}
```

Class:Client

```
package chatting;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Client {

Socket s;

public Client(String ip, int port, String name){
    if (ip.equalsIgnoreCase("localhost")){
        Chatting.server = new Server();
    }
    new Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            try{
                s = new Socket(ip, port);
                System.out.println("CONNECTION >> Waiting for conformation with name "+name+"!");
                send("#reg"+name);
                WaitForMessage("#confirmed");
                System.out.println("CONNECTION >> You have been registered to server!");
                while (true){
                    List<String> recieve = recieve();
                    if (!recieve.isEmpty()){
                        for (String str : recieve){
                            System.out.println(str);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();
}

public void send(String msg){
    try{
        OutputStream os = s.getOutputStream();
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os), true);
        pw.write(msg);
        pw.flush();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public List<String> recieve(){
    List<String> r = new ArrayList<String>();
    try{
        InputStream is = s.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine())!=null){
            System.out.println("CRECIEVE >> "+line);
            r.add(line);
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return r;
}

public void WaitForMessage(String msg){
    while (true){
        if (recieve().contains(msg)) break;
    }
}
}
```

Class:Server

```
package chatting;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class Server {

ServerSocket ss;
List<Socket> s;
HashMap<String, String> registered;

public Server(){
    s = new ArrayList<Socket>();
    registered = new HashMap<String, String>();
    try {
        ss = new ServerSocket(1234);
        System.out.println("SERVER >> created server on port 1234!");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    new Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            while (true){
                try{
                    Socket socket = ss.accept();
                    if (socket != null){
                        System.out.println("SERVER >> client connected "+socket.getLocalAddress().toString());
                        s.add(socket);
                    }
                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
    new Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            while (true){
                for (Socket s : s){
                    List<String> result = translate(recieve(s));
                    if (!result.isEmpty()){
                        for (String str : result){
                            if (str.startsWith("#reg")){
                                str = str.replaceAll("#reg", "");
                                registered.put(s.getInetAddress().toString(), str);
                                System.out.println("SERVER >> user "+str+" on "+s.getLocalAddress().toString()+" registered!");
                                send(s, "#confirmed");
                            }else{
                                sendToAll(registered.get(s.getLocalAddress().toString())+" >> "+str);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
}

public void send(Socket s, String str){
    try{
        OutputStream os = s.getOutputStream();
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os), true);
        pw.write(str);
        pw.flush();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public List<String> translate(String[] str){
    List<String> r = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String s : str){
        r.add(s);
    }
    return r;
}

public String[] recieve(Socket s){
    String[] r = null;
    try{
        ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
        InputStream is = s.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("SRECIEVE >> "+line);
            lines.add(line);
        }
        r = new String[lines.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++){
            r[i] = lines.get(i);
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return r;
}

public void sendToAll(String str){
    for (Socket soc : s){
        send(soc, str);
    }
}
```

My problem is simply no messages get received / sent.
When I start the server it starts the client and connects perfectly, but when I get to

```
try{
                s = new Socket(ip, port);
                System.out.println("CONNECTION >> Waiting for conformation with name "+name+"!");
                send("#reg"+name);
                WaitForMessage("#confirmed");
                System.out.println("CONNECTION >> You have been registered to server!");
                while (true){
                    List<String> recieve = recieve();
                    if (!recieve.isEmpty()){
                        for (String str : recieve){
                            System.out.println(str);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Nothing happens anymore.

Comment: Never wrap a stream more than once unless you *really* know what you are doing or you *really* like confusion. Wrap the input and output streams of the Socket only once in the life of the Socket.

Comment: what error you have @RoflFrankoc ?

Comment: @PeterLawrey is that really causing it to not reach it's destination?

Comment: @YoucefLaidani I am not getting an error it just doesn't send/get recieved.

Comment: The posted code doesn't even compile.

Comment: @JamesKPolk yeah I had problems pasting it in to the textarea, but i can ensure you that what I have in my ide the code gives no errors

Comment: Please copy and paste the exact code you are having trouble with, otherwise we end up wasting our time trying to figure out what the problem is.

Comment: @RoflFrankoc it can cause you to discard data. The BufferedReader by design reads as much as it can. If you discard it you will be discarding anything you didn't read from the buffer. Note: flush() doesn't do anything for an unbuffered stream.

Comment: @PeterLawrey what do you mean, aren't I letting it read everything?

Comment: @RoflFrankoc good point you are reading everything until the socket is closed so there won't be anything after it.

Comment: @RofFrankoc Your assurance is worthless. What matters is that *this code* doesn't complle. Fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You're reading lines but you aren't writing lines. Use `println()` instead of `write()`. And fix everything that @PeterLawrey mentioned too. And if `readLine()` returns null, close the socket and stop reading.